# With BigQuery SELECT * EXCEPT (), use string matching to select column names to include in EXCEPT ()

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to use BigQuery's `SELECT * EXCEPT()` syntax to remove a large number of columns from my table. These columns all have similar strings in their column names, and it would be great if I could string / pattern match on this relevant part of the column name to select / remove these columns.

As a small example, let's say we have the following table:

```
WITH 
  my_table AS (
    SELECT 'nick' as name, 24 as age, 'blue' as color, 7 as num_1, 11 as num_2, 13 as num_3
    UNION ALL SELECT 'joey' as name, 23 as age, 'blue' as color, 8 as num_1, 13 as num_2, 18 as num_3
  )

SELECT * EXCEPT (num_1, num_2, num_3) FROM my_table
```

The above approach works fine for removing a small # of columns, in this case 3, however it would be great if I could do something like:

```
SELECT * EXCEPT (contains "num_") FROM my_table
```

...that takes advantage of the fact that I'd like to remove all of the columns that contain `num_` as part of the column name. Is there a way to do this currently?

Comment: I have not tried this. Wouldn't a `where` clause filter the rows, not remove the columns?

Comment: obviously above advise will not work for your case as it is applicable for filtering rows and not columns

Comment: so, the answer on your question is - absolutely no way to do so unless BigQuery Team will implement such a feature for which you need to submir feature request. SO is not proper place for such request obviously - the right place is  [issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162659)

Comment: btw, usually workaround in such cases  - is rethinking the case and compromising on expected output - for example if you would accept getting output in flattened (kind of unpivot) way - like for example - something like: rowid, column_name, value - this would be easily done

Comment: don't think above qualified as an answer - so put those as comments - hope was helpful. btw for 4 years that I am on SO - I think this is the first time when I said something like "absolutely no way to do so" :o)

Comment: I agree with @MikhailBerlyant here, this is not feasible in BigQuery and I also encourage you to submit a feature request to [issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162659)